# Передать json объект от одной html страницы к другой

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

У меня есть простейшее Flask приложение с всего одной таблицей
Код питоновский вот такой:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    items = long_db_request()
    return render_template("index.html", items=items)


@app.route('/extended')
def extended():
    return render_template("animals.html")
```

Переменная items это большой json объект.

Я создаю таблицу, которая отражает те данные, которые там есть:

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">id</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">creation time</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">animals</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">number</th>
    </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ item.id }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.time }} </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{url_for('extended', name=item.id )}}"> {{ item.name }} </a>
                </td>
                <td> {{item.group}} </td>
                <td>{{ item.group|length }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

И таблица выглядит вот так:
[image]

Как видно, столбец animal содержит слишком много объектов для отображения, что делает таблицу неудобным для чтения.

Хочется, чтобы таблица выглядела так:
[image]

Что намного проще для восприятия и  `show animals` была бы просто ссылкой на другой страницу, где бы отображался чистый json.

Мой вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать?

Я смотрел документацию, есть функция [url_for()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) но в этом случае придется передавать json в урле, что недопустимо..

Как перейти от первого варианта к красивому второму?
Код с первой таблицей находится по  [ссылке](https://bitbucket.org/ivanwolodin/pass-json-from-html-to-html/)

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Правильно говорить - "wolves". Передавайте в url `id` того объекта, JSON которого надо показать.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за ответ! Но id доступно внутри home(), а после перенаправления в extended() по id уже нельзя будет восстановить объект исходный